# To find possible orders of a group given some conditions.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that K is a proper subgroup of H and H is a proper subgroup of G. If order of K is 42 and order of G is 420, what are the possible orders of group H?

- Now as K is subgroup of H & H is subgroup of G; by Lagrange's theorem; order of subgroup divides order of group. But given that these subgroups are proper we can have the condition that order of H lies on between 42 & 420.

So the possible orders i guess are 84 and 210.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes 84 and 210 are the possible orders

Comment: In that case, I agree.

Comment: Yes I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good thing to use is the index of the subgroups and find all the groups. Since $K < H < G$ we have that:

$$[G:K] = [G:H][H:K]$$

But $[G:K] = 10$ and as $[G:H] \not = 1; [H:K] \not = 1$ we have only two possibilities for $[H:K]$ (or for $[G:H]$), as $10$ has only $2$ prime divisors. Now use $[G:H] = \frac{|H|}{|K|}$ to get all possible orders for $H$.

Comment: Your approach is better than mine

Comment: @K.S It's more or less the same thing, as eventually the Lagrange Thorem is proven like this, but it's far better to deal with numbers like 10, than 420 or 42.

Comment: Yes I do agree.